# Use of Flatbuffer Union caused double free or corruption error

Tags: c++, delete-operator, memory-corruption, flatbuffers, double-free

I'm getting the following error at the end of my program execution:

> *** Error in `./bin/test': double free or corruption (out): 0x00007ffd34dab0d0 ***
>   Aborted

I am currently testing the object-based API (--gen-object-api) from Flatbuffer for C++. My main-file looks like this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    flatbuffers::FlatBufferBuilder builder;
    auto dataTest = event::ByteBufferT();
    dataTest.Bytes.push_back(1);
    dataTest.Bytes.push_back(2);

    event::EventDataUnion unionD;
    unionD.type = event::EventData_ByteBuffer;
    unionD.value = &dataTest;

    auto eventOffset = event::CreateEvent(builder,
                       builder.CreateString("byteDataEvent"), 10,
                       event::EventData_ByteBuffer, unionD.Pack(builder));

    builder.Finish(eventOffset);

    auto eventOutput = event::GetEvent(builder.GetBufferPointer());
    auto vec(eventOutput->data_as_ByteBuffer()->Bytes());

    for (auto it = vec->begin(); it != vec->end(); ++it) {
        std::cout << "ByteData: " << int(*it) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I know where the error occurs, but I do not know how I can avoid it. The valgrind-output looks like this:

```
==6242== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==6242==    at 0x4C2A360: operator delete(void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:507)
==6242==    by 0x4031C3: event::EventDataUnion::Reset() (event_generated.h:725)
==6242==    by 0x4028F5: event::EventDataUnion::~EventDataUnion() (event_generated.h:78)
==6242==    by 0x401320: main (main.cpp:118)
==6242==  Address 0xfff0000d0 is on thread 1's stack
==6242==  in frame #3, created by main (main.cpp:8)
==6242== 
==6242== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==6242==    at 0x4C2A360: operator delete(void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:507)
==6242==    by 0x406373: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<signed char>::deallocate(signed char*, unsigned long) (new_allocator.h:110)
==6242==    by 0x405FC6: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<signed char> >::deallocate(std::allocator<signed char>&, signed char*, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:383)
==6242==    by 0x40585D: std::_Vector_base<signed char, std::allocator<signed char> >::_M_deallocate(signed char*, unsigned long) (stl_vector.h:178)
==6242==    by 0x404DA4: std::_Vector_base<signed char, std::allocator<signed char> >::~_Vector_base() (stl_vector.h:160)
==6242==    by 0x403C5E: std::vector<signed char, std::allocator<signed char> >::~vector() (stl_vector.h:425)
==6242==    by 0x403109: event::ByteBufferT::~ByteBufferT() (event_generated.h:260)
==6242==    by 0x40132C: main (main.cpp:114)
==6242==  Address 0x5a021d0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 2 free'd
==6242==    at 0x4C2A360: operator delete(void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:507)
==6242==    by 0x406373: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<signed char>::deallocate(signed char*, unsigned long) (new_allocator.h:110)
==6242==    by 0x405FC6: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<signed char> >::deallocate(std::allocator<signed char>&, signed char*, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:383)
==6242==    by 0x40585D: std::_Vector_base<signed char, std::allocator<signed char> >::_M_deallocate(signed char*, unsigned long) (stl_vector.h:178)
==6242==    by 0x404DA4: std::_Vector_base<signed char, std::allocator<signed char> >::~_Vector_base() (stl_vector.h:160)
==6242==    by 0x403C5E: std::vector<signed char, std::allocator<signed char> >::~vector() (stl_vector.h:425)
==6242==    by 0x403109: event::ByteBufferT::~ByteBufferT() (event_generated.h:260)
==6242==    by 0x4031BB: event::EventDataUnion::Reset() (event_generated.h:725)
==6242==    by 0x4028F5: event::EventDataUnion::~EventDataUnion() (event_generated.h:78)
==6242==    by 0x401320: main (main.cpp:118)
==6242== 
==6242== 
==6242== HEAP SUMMARY:
==6242==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6242==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 7 frees, 1,219 bytes allocated
==6242== 
==6242== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==6242== 
==6242== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==6242== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 1)
```

My flatbuffer-file (event.fbs) looks like this:

```
// event.fbs   
namespace event;

table TableData {
    param1:string;
    param2:uint;
}

table ByteBuffer {
    Bytes:[byte];
}

struct StructData {
    x:float;
    y:float;
}

union EventData {
    TableData,
    StructData,
    ByteBuffer,
    String:string,
}

table Event {
  name:string (key);
  timestamp:ulong = -1;
  data:EventData;
}

root_type Event;
```

My Output is correct, except for the error:

```
 ByteData: 1
 ByteData: 2
 *** Error in `./bin/test': double free or corruption (out): 0x00007ffd34dab0d0 ***
Aborted
```

**Update:**

Without the object API would it look like this?:

```
flatbuffers::FlatBufferBuilder builder;
signed char inv_data[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
auto byteBuffer = event::CreateByteBuffer(builder, builder.CreateVector(inv_data, 10));
auto event = event::CreateEvent(builder, builder.CreateString("byteDataEvent"), 10, event::EventData_ByteBuffer, byteBuffer.Union());
builder.Finish(event);
```

And then I would pass the builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is likely here:

```
unionD.value = &dataTest;
```

The union object expects to own the value it points to, and will delete it at the end. But it is also deleted as a local variable.

You are mixing the usage of two APIs, the object API (for `ByteBuffer` and `EventData`) and the standard API (for `Event`). This is perfectly fine, but may not be what you intended (the former is used for convenience/storage, the latter for speed). The object API in general is a self-contained tree of objects that owns its children.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I updated my question and added an example without the object API. Is that the fastest solution?

Comment: Yup, that is fastest, as you don't allocate any additional memory.

Comment: Note: you would not "pass the builder". You want to pass the buffer the builder created, e.g. `builder.GetBufferPointer()` and `builder.GetSize()`